# Player projectile shooting

Tags: c#, unity3d

I am wondering if my code is needlessly redundant. I noticed, when looking over my code, that I had a unnecessary variable and `if` statement. Both `Fire()` methods achieve the desired result without error (from what I have seen). To me, the redundant `Fire()` method reads a lot nicer and is my preferable method but I'm just wondering if the alternate `Fire()` method is still worth the trade-off in readability due to efficiency. I am also wondering if there may be any underlying bugs that may occur in either of my methods that I am unaware of.

**Unity version:** 4.6.3

**Fire()` method result:** when the <kbd>space</kbd> key is pressed, it spawns a laser that fires upwards towards the enemy at the preset speed and is delayed by the reload time.

**Desired result:** when the <kbd>space</kbd> key is pressed, spawns a laser and has it fire in an upwards direction towards the enemies at the preset speed and than have a delay equal to the preset reload time.

**Variables:**

```
public float reloadTime = 0.2f;
public GameObject playerProjectilePrefab;
public float playerProjectileSpeed = 10f;

private bool canShoot = true;
private float reloadCountDown;
```

**Redundant Fire Method:**

```
void Fire (){
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0 ,(renderer.bounds.size.y * 0.5f), 0);

    if (canShoot && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        canShoot = false;
        GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, playerProjectileSpeed, 0);
        reloadCountDown = reloadTime;
    } else if (!canShoot){
        reloadCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (reloadCountDown <= 0f){
        canShoot = true;
    }
}
```

**Alternate Fire Method:**

```
void Fire (){
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0 ,(renderer.bounds.size.y * 0.5f), 0);

    if (reloadCountDown <= 0f && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, playerProjectileSpeed, 0);
        reloadCountDown = reloadTime;
    } else if (reloadCountDown > 0f){
        reloadCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the **Alternate Fire Method** but I would convert the `canShoot` field to a `CanShoot` property.  Also `startPosition` is only used within the `then` block, so I would move its definition there as well.  Example:

```
public bool CanShoot => reloadCountDown <= 0F;

private void Fire ()
{
    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (CanShoot)
    {
        Vector3 startPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0 ,(renderer.bounds.size.y * 0.5f), 0);
        GameObject playerProjectile = Instantiate(playerProjectilePrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        playerProjectile.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, playerProjectileSpeed, 0);
        reloadCountDown = reloadTime;
    } 
    else 
    {
        reloadCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Your code looks more Java-ish than C#.  Since you've tagged it with `C#`, I will focus my comments on that.  However, I am not familiar with `Unity3d` and don't know how it will like some syntax changes.

**Braces on a new line**

With C#, we prefer braces on their own line.  The one exception would be a one-liner such as:

```
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) { return; }
```

**Fields should never be public**

Your first 3 class-level variables are called `fields`.  They should either be `properties` or `constants`.  For example, will `reloadTime` always be 0.2f?  If so, it can be a constant.  If not, and if you want it to be exposed publicly, then you should make it a property.  If `reloadTime` does not need to be public, then it can remain a field.

**Method, Property, & Constant Names are CamelCase**

**Fields & Parameter Names are PascalCase**

This doesn't YET apply to your original code, but let's combine it with the previous section.  Your declarations could now look like:

```
public const float ReloadTime = 0.2F;
public GameObject PlayerProjectilePrefab { get; private set; }
public const float PlayerProjectileSpeed = 10F;

private bool CanShoot => reloadCountDown <= 0.F;
private float reloadCountDown;
```

But I am just guessing as to the private setters.  Use what your app requires.

**Numeric Type Designators should be Uppercase**

Change the `f` to `F`.  Really doesn't affect your code here but the reason for this guideline is you ever use `long` where a lowercase `l` could be confused as a numeric `1`, but a capital `L` would not.

**Always declare accessibility modifier**

Instead of simply `void Fire()` use `private void Fire()`.  When I see a `private` missing, I assume a newbie coder has forgotten it, which leads me to wonder what else he or she has forgotten.

**Variable declaration and scoping**

As mentioned at the very top with `startPosition`, you should limit the scope of a variable to where you need it.  In my example, `startPosition` was placed inside the `then` block and declared immediately before the one place where it was referenced.  Someone reading your code doesn't have to remember where it was defined, or worry about it afterwards.

Comment: In Unity, in the editor, you can attach a script to a GameObject.  You can then adjust the values of the public fields for that GameObject, but not its properties, so they are not an option.  An alternative is to have a private field with a [SerializeField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) attribute above it.  You could then add a property to access the private field for other classes if you wanted.